# leaflet and angularjs UI not updating until I touch the screen on mobile

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, leaflet

Long story short. I have an app built in ionic framework and using leaflet.js as map interface. I am loading a lot different layer. One of the layers are weather Radar which is WMS layers and I am getting  them in png8 format. I animate the radar layers on leaflet map with loops and $timeouts which works great on browser but on mobile if I touch the screen while the animation is running, it show the animation,  if not UI is not updating with the animation layers. I don't know who can answer this question.

Comment: If you could add some code it would be cool :)

Comment: thanks for getting back Davide, I was able to work around the issue with time intervals. For some reason loop and $timeout was creating the issue. Using $interval resolved the issue and the radar is animating good now.

Comment: It's nice to know :)